# Validation Error in Angular App with Laravel API

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have Angular App with Laravel API and when I try to update it is generating Validation error here

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models.
Employee.php

```
protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

     public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }
```

Salary.php

```
protected $fillable = ['salary','from_date','to_date'];

    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

EmployeeUpdate Controller is

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }
 $employee->update($request->validate([
        'emp_no' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'hire_date' => 'required'
]));
$employee->salaries()->update($request->validate([
'emp_no' => 'required',
        'salary' => 'required',
        'from_date' => 'required',
        'to_date' => 'required'

    ]));
    return response($employee, 200);
}
```

api route for update

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

my data.service.ts is like this

```
updateData(id: string, data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/'+id, data);
  }
```

and employee-edit.component.ts

```
updateEmployee() {
    this.dataService.updateData(this.id, this.employee).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      this.employee = this.data;
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

this is my update salary form

```
<h4>Salary Details</h4>
 
 <div class="salary-details" *ngFor="let salary of employee.salaries">
   <div class="table">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="salary" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Salary</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">From Date</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.from_date">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To Date</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.to_date">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
   </div>
 </div>
```

but when I try to update Employee Model data is updating well but not updating Salary Model data inspect Response encounting folllowing error
`"The salary field is required. (and 2 more errors)"`
`"The salary field is required."`
`"The from date field is required."`
`The to date field is required.`

Then how could I fix this problem?

**update**
My dd($request->all()); is

```
array:10 [ // app\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController.php:40
  "emp_no" => 1
  "birth_date" => "1983-10-05"
  "first_name" => "bambu"
  "last_name" => "Kannangara"
  "gender" => "male"
  "hire_date" => "2023-09-18"
  "created_at" => null
  "updated_at" => null
 
  "salaries" => array:1 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "emp_no" => 1
      "salary" => "9000"
      "from_date" => "2023-09-22"
      "to_date" => "2023-09-19"
      "created_at" => "2023-10-09T08:17:26.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2023-11-17T06:10:14.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Is it an error from the API and if so, what is there a stack trace?
Also in `data.service.ts` parameter `data` of function `updateData` is of type `any`, if you change it to the correct payload type, you can eliminate unwanted side effects in the front end.

Comment: Check the request data `dd($request->all())`. Inside the controller. Also check the data that you will send if it is complete.

Comment: @xenooooo where should I put dd($request->all()); just after `$employee = Employee::find($id);` ?

Comment: you can put it before

Comment: @xenooooo it is comming all data including editable input valurs please check my update question

Comment: @SamuelFerdary it is working fine with POST MAN but problem with Angular Frontend and my employee model also updated fine problems with only Salary Model Update

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use Angular but based on the result of `$request->all()`, the reason there's a validation error is because the `salary`,`from_date` and `to_date` can't be detect based on your validation rules because it is inside the array of `salaries`.

To validate them you need to change your validation rules to this :

```
$employee->salaries()->update($request->validate([
    'salaries.*.salary' => 'required',
    'salaries.*.from_date' => 'required',
    'salaries.*.to_date' => 'required',
]));
```